# Fixing right-click context menu (Sublime Text 2)

Tags: launcher, menu, sublime-text

After a botched attempt to update Sublime Text 2, I've managed to recover and reinstall, but Ubuntu 12.04's context menu "pointers" seem to be screwed up: the right-click will still list "Sublime Text 2" as the first "Open With" option, but clicking on it results in... nothing. No launch, no reaction at all.

Clearly something isn't pointing to something in the right way any more. How do I tell the right-click launcher where to point for the "correct" Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can try fixing the application's individual settings (in Ubuntu 12.04 onwards w/ Unity). In your terminal, enter:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

Now paste the following and save the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sublime Text 2
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=sublime %f
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=sublime -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Hopefully now Sublime Text 2 will work fine from your right click context menu.